# Access Azure SQL Server on Azure VM via SQL Server Management Studio on my local Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine, vnet

I'm sure this is out there somewhere but I can't find it and my brain hurts.

I have a VM on Azure. It has SQL Server running on it and connected with Azure SQL Databases which I can access it locally on the VM no problem but I would like to manage it from my local system/computer via SQL Server Management Studio.

So when I tried to access got this error:

[image: error]

Is this possible to login with the azure sql locally.

Note : I can connect VM server inside the RDP as well as the local system.

Answer (score 0):

Your Azure SQL Database has [Private Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview) enabled, and public IP access disabled.  Or it's a [Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-public-endpoint-securely) with Public IP access disabled.

So your options are.

1) Enable the Public IP Endpoint on the Azure SQL Server or Managed Instance.

2) VPN to a network that is routed to your Azure private network.

3) Continue to RDP into a VM in Azure and manage the database over an RDP 
session.

4) Create a [Point-to-Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) to give your computer a VPN connection into your Azure VNet.